# SQLAlchemy Adjacency List - Constrain parent_id not equal to ID

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, constraints

I'm implementing an Adjacency List in SQL Alchemy which I have working. It's the basic example [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/self_referential.html) of Node. I have it working.

```
class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'node'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('node.id'))
    data = Column(String(50))
    children = relationship("Node")
```

But, I want to enforce a constraint where the `parent_id != id`. That is, a row can not be its own parent. I am not sure how to enforce this. Do I need to use a `@validates` or is there a DB constraint I can set up on the column(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use either `@validates` or a db constraint.  The constraint would look like this:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'node'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('node.id'))
    data = sa.Column(sa.String(50))
    children = orm.relationship("Node")

    __table_args__ = (sa.CheckConstraint('parent_id != id'),)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to add a @validates method, but I will keep the CheckConstraint in mind for the future.